# TortoiseGit how to clone a folder structure

Tags: tortoisegit

I do not want to clone the whole repository.  We have a repository that is 300 MB, and I just only want the folder called /sourcecode, instead of downloading the whole root folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The feature itself is not yet available for TortoiseGit: see [issue 1599](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/1599) (January 2013).

So it should be a simple checkout, except you need to edit first `.git/info/sparse-checkout`, as describe in "[Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/6309)".

Be aware that it is still buggy with msysgit1.8.1 though. See "[Why does git sparse checkout leave behind directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15619112/6309)".

Comment: After editing the `.git/info/sparse-checkout`, can I just do `TortoiseGit->Pull...` and expect that it will sync only what's specified in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`?

Comment: @Danijel Yes, provided you have set `git config core.sparsecheckout true`. see https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42626918/6309