# How do I convert full checkout to sparse checkout?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

Having a full checkout of a repository, how can I convert it into a sparse checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
```

then create `.git/info/sparse-checkout`

```
/*
!excluded-dir/
```

then run

```
git checkout master
```

and `excluded-dir` will disappear.

My problem was that I did not put a trailing slash behind the excluded directory in my `.git/info/sparse-checkout` Much thanks to http://www.richsomerfield.com/post/2014-03-05-adventures-in-git-sparsecheckouts/